# Structure of XQuery / Inserting an XML declaration into output

Tags: xml, xquery

I've written an XQuery script, and it does exactly what I want it to do.  The only problem is that I can't figure out how to get it to output an XML declaration at the beginning.  I can get it to work with a script that just contains

```
unescaped-data('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>')
```

But if I put that at the beginning of my own script, I get thrown errors.  I have a feeling it may be due to the way I wrote the script, but I'm at a loss as to how to solve it.

I won't post the entire script, because I believe it is largely irrelevant.  But I'll show how it starts and ends.

```
<feed>
{
    for $entry in doc('feed.xml')/entries/entry
    .
    .
    .
}
</feed>
```

I start it with an explicit root element 'feed', and I believe that might be my problem.
Inserting the `unescaped-data('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>')` before the `<feed>` element gives me this error (Using Kawa 1.9.1)

```
myxq.xq:2:2: node test when context item is undefined [XPDY0002]
myxq.xq:3:1: saw unexpected '{' - assume you meant '(' [XPST0003]
```

I tried wrapping the unescaped-data in braces, brackets, etc, but I'd just get different errors.  As I said, I feel like I've structured my query 'wrong', but don't know what to do from here.

Comment: You cannot create the XML declaration using XQuery itself. The XML declaration is not even really part of the XML document - it's a parsing hint that is created when a document is serialized (i.e. saved to disk). All you can do is instruct the serializer to create one. And how that is done depends on what serializer you use.

Answer (score 6):

You can't force the XML declaration that way. If you are using *XML* as *output method*, the XML declaration *usually* would be generated automatically as default. If you are using XQuery 1.0, check your processor configuration and options for choosing the *output method* and turning on or off the `omit-xml-declaration` option. XML serialization is non-standard in XQuery 1.0.

If you use Saxon, for example, the XML declaration would be produced as default for with a XML output method, and you could turn its generation on or off using:

```
declare option saxon:output "omit-xml-declaration=no";
```

Other processors might accept something like `omit-xml-declaration="no"` or a command-line option.

XQuery 3.0 has a serialization spec, so if you are using XQuery 3.0 you could control these options in a standard manner using a namespace:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:omit-xml-declaration "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to try disabling the Adobe Acrobat Add-on :-/

Comment: Why? Is this really related to the question?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, if I originally wanted to post this to another question but:
I had problems getting a proper XML-preview of a database return in the browser and after debugging for hours and trying to fix the returned mime type etc. including the xml declaration, I realised, deactivating Adobe Acrobat Add-on was the key…